# How to use Assetic with CacheBustingWorker and twig

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

As i can see Assetic made some progress on CacheBusting:
https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic#cache-busting

But i dont really understand how i should use this.
Can this be used from within twig:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/mybundle/css/fonts.css' 
               'bundles/mybundle/css/style.css'
               'bundles/mybundle/css/screen.css'
               filter='cssrewrite'
 %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

And with the usual `assetic:dump` command?

Where would i have to hook the CacheBustingWorker in?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Cache buster is now part of symfony/AsseticBundle** (Version >= 2.5.0).

Change AsseticBundle version in composer.json like that:

```
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.5.0",
```

And activate cache busting for assets in your config.yml file like that

```
assetic:
    workers:
        cache_busting: ~
```

My JS files are now looking like that:

```
web/bundles/js/projectname-876f9ee.js
```

See https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/pull/119#issuecomment-28877145

Comment: This should definately be the highest rated answer. Super simple solution that does exactly what I was looking for. Why is this not in the Symfony documentation?

Answer (score 5):

I have been recently looking how to do the same.

The solution I came up with was to override Symfony's AssetFactory with my own  class and add the CacheBustingWorker in its constructor. Basically you create a file like the following:

```
<?php
namespace YourSite\YourBundle\Factory;

use Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Factory\AssetFactory as BaseAssetFactory;
use Assetic\Factory\Worker\CacheBustingWorker;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class AssetFactory extends BaseAssetFactory
{
    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel, ContainerInterface $container, ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag, $baseDir, $debug = false)
    {
        parent::__construct($kernel, $container, $parameterBag, $baseDir, $debug);
        // Add CacheBustingWorker
        $this->addWorker(new CacheBustingWorker(CacheBustingWorker::STRATEGY_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

and then change the assetic.asset_factory.class parameter to point to this new class in your config. In my case I added the following to config.yml:

```
parameters:
  assetic.asset_factory.class: YourSite\YourBundle\Factory\AssetFactory
```

Comment: thanks, i also found there is a PR pending to integrate in AsseticBundle: https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/pull/119

Answer (score 4):

With the current implementation of assetic, I needed to update your code to the following to get this to work. Also note if you are using xdebug, you must up the max nesting level - xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200 to more than 100.

```
<?php

namespace YourSite\YourBundle\Factory;

use Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Factory\AssetFactory as BaseAssetFactory;
use Assetic\Factory\LazyAssetManager;
use Assetic\Factory\Worker\CacheBustingWorker;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class AssetFactory extends BaseAssetFactory
{
    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel, ContainerInterface $container, ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag, $baseDir, $debug = false)
    {
        parent::__construct($kernel, $container, $parameterBag, $baseDir, $debug);
        // Add CacheBustingWorker
        $this->addWorker(new CacheBustingWorker(new LazyAssetManager(new BaseAssetFactory($kernel, $container, $parameterBag, $baseDir, $debug))));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

As the assetic code changed again, there is no need of Stategy on LazyAssetManager on the master branch.

Do not forget to change your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "dev-master@dev",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master@dev"
}
```

You now just need this:

```
namespace YourSite\YourBundle\Factory;

use Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Factory\AssetFactory as BaseAssetFactory;
use Assetic\Factory\Worker\CacheBustingWorker;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class AssetFactory extends BaseAssetFactory
{
    public function __construct(
        KernelInterface $kernel,
        ContainerInterface $container,
        ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag,
        $baseDir,
        $debug = false
    ) { 
        parent::__construct($kernel, $container, $parameterBag, $baseDir, $debug);
        // Add CacheBustingWorker
        $this->addWorker(new CacheBustingWorker());
    }
}
```

Do not forget to `php app/console cache:clear -e prod` before dumping assets one time to avoid standard filenames to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
assetic:
    workers:
        cache_busting: ~
```

Is the answer.

Comment: Yes, its already in the answer from Juergen. I changed it to the accepted answer.